# Trying to take away a value inSQL

Tags: php, sql

I am coding this e-commerce website in PHP and SQL (for a computing project) and don't know how I would go about updating the stock. I have an UPDATE statement like this:

```
$sql = "
        UPDATE stock 
        SET stock_Qty = [minus]'$purchased_qty'
        WHERE stockID = '$stockID'";
```

Obviously this wouldn't work as it stands. I don't know what to put in those brackets.

can you do math operations in SQL? If so how?
thanks

Comment: `SET stock_Qty = stock_Qty - $purchased_qty`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, math is simple in SQL

```
$sql = "UPDATE `stock` 
        SET `stock_Qty` = `stock_Qty` - $purchased_qty
        WHERE `stockID` = '$stockID'";
```